# delegate: no response, where is the secret?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have a little trouble with my delegate example. I created a very simple code to learn how delegates work. I know that my delegate not will be called but i can't figure out why?
So here is the complete code. Please tell me what i do wrong. It is really important for me to understand the error in this code.

First Viewcontroller: h.file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol ViewControllerDelegate;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end


@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)transfer:(ViewController *)data number:(NSUInteger)value;

@end
```

First Viewcontroller: m.file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize delegate;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(transfer:number:)]){
        [delegate transfer:self number:65];
        NSLog(@"delegate called");
    }
    [delegate transfer:self number:65]; //Try to call without if-statement.
}

@end
```

SecondViewcontroller: h.file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

SecondViewcontroller: m.file

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)transfer:(ViewController *)data number:(NSUInteger)value
{
    NSLog(@"received information from ViewController");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewController *viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    viewcontroller.delegate = self;
}

@end
```

In the storyboard i use two container views so both ViewControllers will shown.

Comment: Try to put an NSLog inside each viewDidLoad, to make sure the order in which they are called.

Comment: you should not retain this delegate '@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;' other wise it may fall in retain cycle. you should use assign.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is fine. The problem appears to be that you are never loading the view controllers view(s) so the `viewDidLoad` method isn't being called.

To test, push the `viewcontroller`, or just request `viewcontroller.view`.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I'm glad about any answer. I changed retain in assign but the delegate still won't work. So i also implement a NSLog at the last line of both ViewDidLoads. I get an output from both ViewDidLoads so this part is fine. I also can see the Views after compilation. In my opinion it should work but it won't. The only logical solution is that i forget something important but what?

Comment: I suspect you're using a storyboard? So the views that are loaded and seen are not the same as the one you create and set yourself as the delegate of... Try pushing it.